# How to access variables inside a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the code:

```
var here;
function setNews(data2){
    here = data2;
    console.log(here);//1st console log
}
console.log(here);//2nd console log
```

in the 1st console log the the data inside here are printed but in the 2nd console log it prints undefined how can i access the data inside the setNews function so that I can use it outside setNews.

Thank you.

Comment: Acutally it should work, can you past the entire code? I'm able to reproduce the behaviour.  `var here;
function setNews(data2){
    here = data2;
    console.log(here);//1st console log
}
setNews("ff");
console.log(here);//2nd console log`

Comment: did you put all this code inside document.ready function? I think your code should work when you put all outside the document.ready. Try that.

Comment: Where did you call the function setNews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var here;
function setNews(data2){
    here = data2;
    console.log("inside function " +here);//1st console log
}
setNews("something");
console.log("outside function" +here);//2nd console log
```

`Fiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/bmArj/

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need to review your architecture.

```
var here;
function setNews(data2){
    here = data2;
    console.log(here);//1st console log
}
//executed immediatly, `here` is not yet initialized by setNews
console.log(here);//2nd console log
```

Variable 'here' is being output to the console immedialy when javascript is loaded, but since it's undefined, console shows 'undefined'.

When later you call setNews('sample'), it will set global variable `here` but there is no point in that, because it was already outputted.

Answer (score 0):

// initialize  this to desired value.

```
var here = "your value";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think...use return...

```
var here = setNews(2);

function setNews(data2){
    here = data2;
    console.log(here);//1st console log

    return here;
}
console.log(here);//2nd console log
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read this article on [JavaScript Variable and Function Hoisting](http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting).

What happened is when you first declare the variable `here`, it wasn't initialized.
When you give `here` a value inside function `setNews()`, its value is not available to the outer `console.log`. 
So you need to call `setNews()` first before displaying the content of `here` in the second call to the console, like so:

```
var here;
function setNews(data2){
    here = data2;
    console.log(here);//1st console log
}
setNews("some data here");
console.log(here);//2nd console log, it will display "some data here"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define a variable, (let's call it "here") that is automatically set to the value of some function named "setNews," then this might work better:

```
var here,
    data2 = "the news!";

// Set value of "here" to processed data2
here = (function (news) {
    // Process news
    news = "This is " + news;
    return news;
})(data2);

console.log(here);
// Prints "This is the news!"
```